# Kotlin coroutine flow example for Android button click event?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, anko

I used to use `Channel` to send out click event from Anko View class to Activity class, however more and more `Channel` functions are marked as deprecated. So I wanted to start using `Flow` apis.

I migrated code below:

```
private val btnProduceChannel = Channel<Unit>()
val btnChannel : ReceiveChannel<Unit> = btnProduceChannel 

// Anko
button {
    onClick {
        btnProduceChannel.send(Unit)
    }
}
```

to:

```
lateinit var btnFlow: Flow<Unit>
    private set

button {
    btnFlow = flow { 
       onClick { 
            emit(Unit) 
       }
    }
}
```

I have to mark flow properties as `var` now which is not so elegant as before. Is this way right? Can I init a Rx `Subject` like `Flow` when defining the property?

---

Edit:

I brought `Channel` back, then used `consumeAsFlow()`:

```
private val btnChannel = Channel<Unit>()

// This can be collected only once
val btnFlow = btnChannel.consumeAsFlow()

// Or add get() to make property can be collected multiple times
// But the "get()" can be easily forgotten and I don't know the performance of create flow every access
val btnFlow get() = btnChannel.consumeAsFlow()


// Send event with btnChannel
```

This seems better than `lateinit var` one, but any way to get rid of `Channel` completely? (Though `Flow` itself like `callbackFlow`, `channelFlow` are using channel)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Although I don't use Anko in my project, I've written this function to use with regular button references, see if it helps you:

```kotlin
fun View.clicks(): Flow<Unit> = callbackFlow {
    setOnClickListener {
        offer(Unit)
    }
    awaitClose { setOnClickListener(null) }
}
```

An example of possible usage is:

```kotlin
button.clicks()
   .onEach { /*React on a click event*/ }
   .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
```

**UPDATE**

As @Micer mentioned in the comments to the original answer, the method `Channel#offer` has become deprecated in the favour of `Channel#trySend` method.

The updated version:

```kotlin
fun View.clicks() = callbackFlow<Unit> {
    setOnClickListener {
        trySend(Unit)
    }
    awaitClose { setOnClickListener(null)}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this useful kotlin extension! This replaces my old `RxView.clicks(view)` :)

Comment: What is the difference between `lifecycleScope.launch` and `.launchIn(lifecycleScope)`?

Comment: guys for some reasona it's not working on AppcompatButton

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky aside from being more convenient in some cases, it's a terminal statement, almost always needs `onEach()` before

Comment: `offer` is deprecated and should be replaced by `trySend`

Answer (score 0):

**For kotlin lover**

Using `callbacFlow`

```
fun View.clicks() = callbackFlow {
setOnClickListener {
    this.trySend(Unit).isSuccess
}
 awaitClose { setOnClickListener(null) }
}
```

*Usage*

```
bind.btn.clicks().onEach {
 // do your staff
}.launchIn(lifecycleScope)
```

Using `Channel` eventActor

```
fun View.setOnClick(action: suspend () -> Unit) {
 // launch one actor as a parent of the context job
 val scope = (context as? CoroutineScope) ?: AppScope
 val eventActor = scope.actor<Unit>(capacity = Channel.CONFLATED) {
     for (event in channel) action()
  }
    // install a listener to activate this actor
    setOnClickListener { eventActor.trySend(Unit).isSuccess }
}
```

*Usage*

```
bind.btn.setOnClick {
    // do your staff
  }
```