# Any(better) approach to pass compose desktop's `onClick` through `callbackFow`?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

I was wondering if it is possible to pass `onClik` [handling `onClick`] through `callbackFlow` as I saw from this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57899296/kotlin-coroutine-flow-example-for-android-button-click-event/57914394#57914394) post.
I was having hard time implementing since the `onClick Callback` was inside parameter also `Button` is function so wasn`t able to implement extension function

anyways  I tried something like

```kotlin
    lateinit var buttonListener :Flow<Unit>



    fun <T >offers(t: T) = callbackFlow {
        offer(t)
    awaitClose { null }
    }

    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        if(::buttonListener.itInitalized){
            buttonListener.collect {
                println("it => Kotlin.Unit")
            }        
        }
    }
    MaterialTheme {

                  Button(
                    onClick = {
                        println("buttonClicked")
                        buttonListener = offers(Unit)

                    } //...
                ) { /** designs */}

    }
```

which is callable only 1 times on every runtime

```
buttonClicked                 <--\ 
Kotlin.Unit => Kotlin.Unit    <--/\__first click
buttonClicked
buttonClicked
buttonClicked
```

yet expecting someting like

```
buttonClicked
Kotlin.Unit => Kotlin.Unit
buttonClicked
Kotlin.Unit => Kotlin.Unit
buttonClicked
Kotlin.Unit => Kotlin.Unit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use coroutine `Channel` instead of `Flow` to receive events from outside the coroutine. Then convert it to `Flow` using `consumeAsFlow()` method.

Now the flow operators like `collect` can be called on this `Flow`.

It can receive multiple `onClick` events from the button composable.

```
var buttonListener = Channel<Unit>()

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    buttonListener.consumeAsFlow().collect {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: $it => Kotlin.Unit")
    }
}

MaterialTheme {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: buttonClicked")
            buttonListener.offer(Unit)
        }
    ){
        Text(text = "Button")
    }
}
```